# Zend 2: How can I get closures in Module.php to accept parameters?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

edit:
I should explain this is for an app that must use\authenticate to multiple dbs. I have all the DB adapters defined in my autoload config like this:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        //Default adapter retrieved with $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter')
        'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=db1;host=myserver',
        'username' => $DBuser,
        'password' => $DBpass,
        //'driver_options' => array(
        //  PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        //),
        'adapters' => array(
            'someDB' => array(
                'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=someDB;host=myserver',
                'username' => $DBuser,
                'password' => $DBpass,
            ),
            'someOtherDB' => array(
                'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=someOtherDB;host=myserver',
                'username' => $DBuser,
                'password' => $DBpass,
                'AppType' => 'myCustomProperty',
...
```

I have the following function I'm trying to move to the service manager:

```
public function getAuthService($db) {
    if (! $this->authService) {
        //All DBs using authentication must have a view_users view
        $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get($db);
        $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);
        $authAdapter
            ->setTableName('view_users')
            ->setIdentityColumn('username')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
        ;
        $authService = new AuthenticationService();
        $authService->setAdapter($authAdapter);
        $this->authService = $authService;
    }
    return $this->authService;
}
```

I have this in the service manager, but how do I modify it so $myParam can to passed when it is retrieved?

```
public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get($myParam);
                $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);
                $authAdapter
                    ->setTableName('view_users')
                    ->setIdentityColumn('username')
                    ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                    ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
                ;
                $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                $authService->setAdapter($authAdapter);

                return $authService;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

The problem is that I want to be able to pass the factory the $db param when retrieving it from the service manager.

To be clear this question isn't specifically about how to authenticate to multiple DBs because this already works fine for me I just want to move my function into the service manager.

edit: crisp answered my actual question, but I found my real issue was a misunderstanding with how to use the Authentication class.

Long story short, I have a login controller that prompts for user creds then checks the user's access against all DBs and stores this info in Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session. Then from various other modules and can just call read() on Session and retrieve authorization info for the user.

Comment: You define different entries for different adapters. There's no parameters like that. Furthermore i'd hardly question the use-case, there's probably a much better way to solve things.

Comment: Not sure I understand. This app must make use multiple DBs. I wanted to be able to register this in the service manager so I can call it up when I need to authenticate to one of them.

Comment: Oh sorry I just realized how that code is confusing. I actually have defined a bunch of adapters in my config for each db. $myParam is just one of those predefined adapters from my autoload config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `AbstractFactory`, which itself is capable of determining from a service name exactly which service to return.

There must be a pattern to the naming of services coming from your abstract factory, I'd suggest for your use case a pattern of `AuthService\DbAdapterName`.

With that in mind you can then write a factory for it such as this one ...

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractFactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class AbstractAuthenticationServiceFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{

    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName) 
    {
        // the name must begin with authservice ($name is the lowercase canonical name)
        if (0 !== strpos($name, 'authservice')) {
            return false;
        }
        // remove authservice from the name, leaving just the db name
        $dbName = str_replace('authservice', '', $name);

        // we can create the service only if the service manager has the db
        return $serviceLocator->has($dbName);
    }

    public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName) 
    {
        $dbName = str_replace('authservice', '', $name);

        $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator->get($dbName);
        $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);
        $authAdapter
            ->setTableName('view_users')
            ->setIdentityColumn('username')
            ->setCredentialColumn('password')
            ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');

        $authService = new AuthenticationService();
        $authService->setAdapter($authAdapter);

        return $authService;
    }
}
```

Once you have your factory, you need to add it to the `service_manager` config under the `abstract_factories` key ...

```
// module.config.php
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
         'abstract_factories' => array(
             'authservice' => 'Application\Service\AbstractAuthenticationServiceFactory',
         ),
     ),
);
```

You can then use the servicelocator to get your `AuthService` instances by using the pattern described earlier

```
$someDbAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService\someDB');

$otherDbAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService\someOtherDB');
```

Comment: Cool, I'm still new to design patterns and this is one in particular I had trouble conceptualizing. Makes more sense now that I actually have a use for it. Although I found all I really needed was to read from Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session this answers my actual question, which admittedly was misguided.